# for provisioning aws instance using terraform in us-east-1and i used data resource to retrieve key pair from us-east-1 region but not worked

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-aws

The keys are available and retrieved and I tested it using output resource and it worked but not worked here with this code as the instance is created in us-east-2 as the provider I used for my terraform code.
the error is:

> Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidKeyPair.NotFound: The key pair 'test_key' does not exist
> │   status code: 400, request id: 2d7f03c2-dce4-42fb-9d35-c88a8a218d36
> │
> │   with aws_instance.instance,
> │   on EC2_instances.tf line 7, in resource "aws_instance" "instance":
> │    7: resource "aws_instance" "instance" {

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "key"
  region = "us-east-1"
}
    
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ami            = var.ami  
  instance_type  = var.instance_type
  key_name       = data.aws_key_pair.report_key.key_name
}

data "aws_key_pair" "report_key" {
  provider = aws.key
  key_name = "test_key"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

keys are **region specific**. So you can't use key from `us-east-1` in `us-east-2`. You have to create and duplicate keys to different regions.

Comment: But in documentation, we have data resources to retrieve its data so I used output as"
` output " key_data"{
value= data.aws_key_pair.report_key.key_name
} `
and the output ran successfully and returned the name of the key also tried with the key ID and returned its value.